# How to open new modal when add radio button validation and submit it JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap5-modal

I don't understand this code. How can I open a new model when clicking a  radio button option and submit it after. I don't understand how to add radio button validation with JavaScript.

After selecting a radio button option, it needs to submit the form and after that I need to open the relevant modal. For example if I have two radio button options, both options need to open the modal when one option is selected and submit.

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item nav1" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true"><i class="fas fa-bars fa-2x" ></i></button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item nav2" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false"><i class="fas fa-bullhorn fa-2x"></i></button>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light rounded-pill border border-light text-center pill" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">+</button>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Get Started</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-check">
              <input id="radio-social" class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="radio-social">Add social media links</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input id="radio-custom" class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" checked>
              <label class="form-check-label" for="radio-custom">Add custom links</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button id="btn" type="button" onclick=" check()" class="btn btn-dark btn" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Add</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Scrollable modal -->
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">
        ...
      </div>
      <h4 id="error" style="color:red"> </h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light rounded-pill border border-light text-center pill" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">+</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container sm-2">
  <table class="table table-borderless">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>
          <i class="fas fa-share-alt-square fa-2x"></i>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <i class="fas fa-plus-square fa-2x"></i>
        </td>
        <td>
          <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h fa-2x"></i>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="container-sm">
  <p class="text-center fs-6 text-white align5">www.logo.com</p>
</div>

<!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

<!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
<!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->

<script>
  function check() {
    document.getElementById("radio-social").checked = true;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things.

- Tag at least one of your radio inputs as `required`
- Give your radio inputs values, so you have something to pass through the form
- Make sure you nest them within a `<form>`
- Make your 'Add' button type="submit" rather than type="button".  That way it will both validate and trigger form submission automatically without javascript.
- Put an onsubmit="" tag to your function in either the  or the <button type="submit" element.
- Remove the `data-bs-dismiss="modal"` tag from your 'Add' button so the modal stays open for form validation.

Putting all that together, we get the following HTML for the form:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Get Started</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <form id="MyForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="modal-form" onsubmit="nextModal()" >
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-check">
            <input id="radio-social" class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" value="social" required>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="radio-social">Add social media links</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check">
            <input id="radio-custom" class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" value="custom" required>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="radio-custom">Add custom links</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button id="btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn">Add</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now we're almost there! Since you're clearly using Bootstrap, I figured JQuery would be ok for the javascript.  Since the validation is already handled, the only thing we need the script to do is close the modal and open the next one, and presumably submit the form somewhere.

```
<script>
function nextModal() {
  $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');     //closes the current modal
  $('#TargetModal').modal('show');      //shows a new modal with id='TargetModal'
  event.preventDefault();               //Keep the page from refreshing without reason
  var form = $('#MyForm')[0];           //Get form element by ID ([0], since it's the first of its kind)
  var formData = new FormData(form);    //Pass the form data to a variable
  $.ajax({                              //Use ajax to send the form response to a php form-handler
    url: '#',                          //Replace # with a form-handler: i.e. filename.php
    type: 'post',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data, status) {
      alert(status);         //Remove this line later. It's just here for demonstration.
      //Optionally, do stuff with whatever data the php file returned i.e. error handling
    },
  });
}
</script>
```